# How to make your own options in PhotoEditorSDK

Tags: ios, photoeditorsdk

I am trying to add my own option in **PhotoEditorSDK 7.0**

```
let tools [
           .tool("MY CONTROL", UIImage(named: "back", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)!, BrushController(configuration: configuration)),
        ]

let controller = PhotoEditViewController.init(photo: sampleImage, menuItems: mymenu , configuration: configuration)
```

### I have created brush controller

How to implement it like its working on Build in brush controller. how to pass my PhotoEditViewController value to my controller

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "how to pass my PhotoEditViewController value to my controller"? Did you try using the latest version?

Comment: @Sascha i am using **PhotoEditorSDK 7.0**. I have created a custom controller for my tool. Its initiated correctly. But how do I pass my edit controller layer like image and text to that controller to perform my task?